# How to repeat every 2 cells in google sheets using api

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to repeat the formula in every 2 cells. For instance A1=formula, B1=blank, C1=formula, D1=blank.
Or fill blanks with 0. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: You asked only one questions: "Is there any possibility to do this?" - where is obvious answer is "yes" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
 function myFunction() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()

    for(x=0; x<10; x++){

    ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, (x*2)+1, 1, 1).setFormula('=yourFormula');
    ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, (x*2)+2, 1, 1).setValue("");

    }
    }
```

You will have to adjust the x<10 depending on how many times you want it to run. If you want that to be a variable please explain so we can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also arrayformula like this way :

```
=arrayformula(if(mod(row(A1:A);2);"my formula";""))
```

or according to your local parameters

```
=arrayformula(if(mod(row(A1:A),2),"my formula",""))
```